# LinkedIn API with /v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=handleString

Tags: java, asp.net, angularjs, wso2, linkedin-api

I have requirement to get the *person ID* from the *linkedin API* 
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=handleString&handleString=test123@gmail.com 
but receiving response below

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-handleString /clientAwareMemberHandles",
    "status": 403
}
```

I have the application permissions in the application  `r_liteprofile/w_member_social/r_emailaddress`

Additionally when I requesting a access token I send these three as scope parameters.

Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This response is from linked in api and not from API manager. Basically, this means that the call from api manager to LinkedIn api does not have a token with the correct permission.

The token which is generated by API Manager is only for authentication with api manager. If the backend server expects a token as well, you should send that particular token in the request from API-M to the backend.

You can achieve this by adding a meditation sequence to your api. Follow the example below.

https://medium.com/@menakajayawardena/wso2-how-to-using-oauth2-protected-back-ends-with-api-manager-5d7e234c61c